# Use differentiation to find a power series

Tags: power-series

Use differentiation to find a power series of
$f(x) = \frac{1}{(8+x)^2}$

$ f'(x) = \frac{-2}{(8+x)^3} $

how do I find the power series of this? I can not go next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{(8+x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{8^{n+1}}
$$
Taking the derivative in both sides: (n=0 is constant)
$$
g'(x) = \frac{-1}{(8+x)^2} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n(-1)^nx^{n-1}}{8^{n+1}}
$$
$$
-f(x) = \frac{-1}{(8+x)^2} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{8^{n+2}}
$$
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n}x^{n}}{8^{n+2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try figure it out through your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To find a series expression for $\frac{2}{(8+x)^2}$, differentiate the power series of (more or less) $\frac{1}{8+x}$. Note that $\frac{1}{8+x}$ has derivative $-\frac{1}{(8+x)^2}$.

To find the series for $\frac{1}{8+x}$, rewrite as $\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{1+x/8}$, and use the familiar series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: I found a power series of $\frac{1}{8+x}$ as  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n*x^n}{8^{n+1}}$
How do I combine it with the derivative?

Comment: The derivative of this is $-\frac{1}{(8+x)^2}$. Differentiate the series you wrote down above term by term. That gives you the series for $-\frac{1}{(8+x)^2}$. Then multiply each term by $-2$ to get the series for your function $\frac{2}{(8+x)^2}$.

Comment: I multiplied both sides by -2 and then I got $\frac{2}{(8+x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}nx^{n-1}2}{8^{n+1}}$
In order to get the left side as same as differentiation of f(x)
I multiplied both sides by $\frac{-1}{2}$ again. so I got  $\frac{-2}{(8+x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n(n-1)x^{n-2}}{8^{n+1}}$

My answer is wrong. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You should have differentiated only once. You are not interested in $\frac{1}{(8+x)^3}$. By the way, in your sum the first term is $0$. Omit it, and change the variable of summation, changing $n-1$ to $k$.

Comment: Oh Cool. Now I understand what I have to do! Thank you a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. The basic idea is that we know the series for $\frac{1}{8+x}$, and $\frac{2}{(8+x)^2}$ is (more or less) the derivative of $\frac{1}{8+x}$, so we can obtain our desired series by differentiating a known series term by term.

Comment: There will probably be quite a number of other instances where you find a series by differentiating or integrating or adding known series. A simple example is the series for $\ln(1+x)$, where we write it as $\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t}\,dt$, write down the series for $\frac{1}{1+t}$ and integrate term by term.